# React: Setting key on component rendered from children

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the warning "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."  using the code below.  If I remove the fragment and wrap it in a div with a key instead, it works, but then each of my components has an extra div with a key. I'm not sure why this solution can't work. According to the docs it should.

```
  <div ref={c => (this._gallery = c)}>
      {thumbs.map((image, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
          {this.props.children({
            margin: margin,
            index: index,
            image: image,
            key: image.key || image.src,
            onClick: onClick ? this.handleClick : null
          })} 
          </React.Fragment>
        );  
      })} 
    </div>
```

The key is correctly appearing in the html:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap each element in Fragment. A `key` should be on the top level element while your top element is Fragment.

```
<div ref={c => (this._gallery = c)}>
  {thumbs.map((image, index) => {
    return (
      {this.props.children({
        margin: margin,
        index: index,
        image: image,
        key: image.key || image.src,
        onClick: onClick ? this.handleClick : null
      })} 
    );  
  })} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the key prop on the 'React.Fragment'.